# getting fields of a section (getFields())

Tags: field, fieldtypes

I feel like I'm doing this wrong (looping on section fields):

```
{% for fieldLayoutField in craft.entries.section('rentalsBulletin').getEntryTypes().first.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
    {% set field = craft.fields.getFieldById(fieldLayoutField.fieldId) %}
    {% include 'rentals-bulletin/_components/form-field-types/' ~ field.type %}
{% endfor %}
```

Building a front-end "create" page. Goal is loop through fields and depending on type include a snippet to build the form. Basically, get section fields and build the form dynamically.

EDIT: if you didn't see the accepted answer comments, the way to do this when you don't have an entry to work with is:

```
{% for fieldLayoutField in craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('rentalsBulletin').getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go through `craft.fields` to get the fields. They are already there.

```
{% set fields = craft.entries.section('rentalsBulletin').getEntryTypes().first.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
{% for field in fields %}
    {% set type = field.getField().type %}
    {% include 'rentals-bulletin/_components/form-field-types/' ~ type %}
{% endfor %}
```

You will probably also want to pass some variables into your included templates to actually build the fields with the proper field names as well.

```
{% set properties = { 'name': field.getField().handle } %}
{% include 'rentals-bulletin/_components/form-field-types/' ~ type with properties %}
```

There are also a few plugins [available on the plugins page](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) for form building that you might want to check out.

**Update** Looks like `craft.entries.section('rentalsBulletin').getEntryTypes()` returns null when there are no entries defined. Instead you can go through a different route that doesn't seem to depend on entries.

```
{% set fields = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('news').getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
```

Comment: Yea that looks much better. Properties piece too! However, I was wanting to avoid grabbing an actual entry in the case there are no entries to grab.

Comment: Yes. I see what you mean about no entries. Definitely use the `getEntryTypes().first` then, if that works. The rest should be the same. I updated the code. ;)

Comment: Hah, actually my technique fails when there are no entries either. Should I just delete this whole question now?

Comment: try this: `{% set fields = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('rentalsBulletin').getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}`

Comment: Nice! That works.

Comment: Might want to check out a nice plugin called 'inspector'. It prints out all properties and methods of an object using {{ object|inspect }}. Great for following the rabbit hole ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19599/discussion-between-veritascs-and-douglas-mcdonald).