# Getting fields of Matrix?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

How can I get the fields of a matrix field? I want to loop through the fields. I have the fields of the section, if the `field.handle` is of type matrix, I want to get the fields of the matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looping through a Matrix field is pretty easy, here is an example. Also read the docs on the Matrix field here - https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrix %}
    {% set handle = block.type.handle %} {# Grab the current block handle #}

    {{ handle }} {# Echo out the handle #}

    {% if handle == 'myMatrixBlock' %}
        {{ myMatrixBlock.heading }}  {# If you have a field called heading in myMatrixBlock #}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

---

**Updated**

Take a look at these examples...

[getting fields of a section (getFields())](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/getting-fields-of-a-section-getfields)

[How to loop through matrix block fields and pull out handle and content?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11068/how-to-loop-through-matrix-block-fields-and-pull-out-handle-and-content)

Comment: I know how to get it when I know the fields. I want to get the fields programatically. In the example you give, I'd like to get `heading` programatically. Do you know how to do it?